# Bootstrap `make` error: cannot remove `docs/assets/bootstrap.zip`

Tags: makefile, twitter-bootstrap

I have applied `make` to a github bootstrap clone (`git clone https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git`) and I receive the following output:

```
mkdir -p bootstrap/img
mkdir -p bootstrap/css
mkdir -p bootstrap/js
cp img/* bootstrap/img/
lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
lessc --compress ./less/bootstrap.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
lessc ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
lessc --compress ./less/responsive.less > bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
cat js/bootstrap-transition.js js/bootstrap-alert.js js/bootstrap-button.js js/bootstrap-carousel.js js/bootstrap-collapse.js js/bootstrap-dropdown.js js/bootstrap-modal.js js/bootstrap-tooltip.js js/bootstrap-popover.js js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js js/bootstrap-tab.js js/bootstrap-typeahead.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
uglifyjs -nc bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.tmp.js
echo "/**\n* Bootstrap.js by @fat & @mdo\n* Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.\n* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt\n*/" > bootstrap/js/copyright.js
cat bootstrap/js/copyright.js bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.tmp.js > bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js
rm bootstrap/js/copyright.js bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.tmp.js
rm docs/assets/bootstrap.zip
rm: cannot remove `docs/assets/bootstrap.zip': No such file or directory
make: *** [docs] Error 1
```

My `bootstrap/bootstrap` folder contains:

```
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-responsive.css
│   └── bootstrap-responsive.min.css
├── img
│   ├── glyphicons-halflings.png
│   └── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
└── js
    ├── bootstrap.js
    └── bootstrap.min.js
```

Do I need to worry about the `make` error, or am I good to go? (I've never used Bootstrap before).

Thanks!
Ryan

**EDIT:**

Applying `make -i` (thanks Beta) produces the following output (continuing on from the above output) and seems to be okay:

```
rm: cannot remove `docs/assets/bootstrap.zip': No such file or directory
make: [docs] Error 1 (ignored)
zip -r docs/assets/bootstrap.zip bootstrap
  adding: bootstrap/ (stored 0%)
  adding: bootstrap/js/ (stored 0%)
  adding: bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js (deflated 82%)
  adding: bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (deflated 74%)
  adding: bootstrap/css/ (stored 0%)
  adding: bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css (deflated 77%)
  adding: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css (deflated 84%)
  adding: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css (deflated 85%)
  adding: bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css (deflated 80%)
  adding: bootstrap/img/ (stored 0%)
  adding: bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png (deflated 4%)
  adding: bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png (deflated 4%)
cp bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js
cp bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
rm -r bootstrap
lessc ./less/bootstrap.less > ./docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css
lessc ./less/responsive.less > ./docs/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css
node docs/build
cp img/* docs/assets/img/
cp js/*.js docs/assets/js/
cp js/tests/vendor/jquery.js docs/assets/js/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much to go on. This error can mean trouble in two ways: 1) Make aborts, when it may have had important things still to do, and 2) the absence of an expected file may indicate that something has gone wrong.

If you want Make to soldier on despite the error, just use `make -i`. This will prevent the first problem, but will do nothing about the underlying problem if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for the help Beta, I pushed through the error using the `make -i` command and it seems to have built it correctly now.